# How does a probability density function of a random variable is induced due to Radon-Nikodyn derivative?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

If someone can please clarify the following for me:
Given a probability space $(\omega,\Sigma,P)$ and a continous random variable $X:w \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$.
I have read the statement of the Radon-Nikodyn Theorem, but I still can't see how does one relate it to the existance of a probability density function. Can someone please elaborate on this?
Thanks

Comment: I see that $m$ is a measure in $\mathcal{R}$ or should I say in $\mathcal{B}(R)$, but $P$ is a measure in $(\omega, \Sigma)$. So how does the theorem applies here?

Comment: I put an answer, that should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb P_X$ the measure on $\mathbb R$ defined by $$\mathbb P_X(B):=\mathbb P\{X\in B\},$$
for all Borel set $B\subset \mathbb R$.

> **Definition** Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Then, $X$ is continuous if $\mathbb P_X$ is absolute continuous with respect to $m$.

Therefore, by Radon-Nikodym, there is $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $$\frac{\mathrm d \mathbb P_X}{\mathrm d m}=f,$$

i.e. $$\mathbb P_X(B)=\int_B f(x)m(\mathrm d x).$$
Therefore, $X$ has a density $f$.

Comment: Just to be sure: $P_{x}(B)$ is defined as $\int _{\omega} 1_{X^{-1}(B)}$ ?

Comment: It's rather $\int_\Omega \boldsymbol 1_{X^{-1}(B)}\mathrm d \mathbb P=\mathbb P\{X\in B\}$, but it's probably what you wanted to say.